# Hooking to HttpApplication.BeginRequest with runtime generated handler causes NullReference Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, handler, expression-trees

After hooking up to an event HttpApplication.BeginRequest (and some other HttpApplication events) with a runtime generated delegate like

```
var expr = Expression.Lambda<EventHandler>(Expression.Empty(),
    new[]
    {
        Expression.Parameter(typeof (object)),
        Expression.Parameter(typeof (EventArgs))
    });
var handler = expr.Compile();
application.BeginRequest += handler;
```

I get an error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
 System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +120
  System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +114
```

Environment: ASP.NET 4.

Exception passes away, if this delegate is invoked in an other delegate call:
`application.BeginRequest += (s, e) =>{handler(s, e);};`

This approach doesn't satisfy me.

The behaviour seems to be specific for HttpApplication, as other classes behave in an expected manner. 
Can someone bring light on this issue, please.

Answer (score 1):

Found out, that it is because of access to `MemberInfo.ReflectedType.ToString()`. In dynamic methods MemberInfo.ReflectedType is Null. ReflectionType it set, if method is created inside a generated type with TypeBuilder.